# How to add Tick event to System::windows::Forms::Timer in unmanaged class

Tags: .net, visual-c++, event-handling, timer, c++-cli

I'm trying to do it like I found in some example :

```
TimerID = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Timer(); 
TimerID->Tick += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Bridge::timer1_Tick);
```

and

```
System::Void Bridge::timer1_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    Bridge::DoUpdate();
}
```

But can't create event handler because of error :

> error C3364: 'System::EventHandler' : invalid argument for delegate
>   constructor; delegate target needs to be a pointer to a member
>   function

Bridge is unmanaged class.
So I'm declaring TimerID this way :

```
gcroot<System::Windows::Forms::Timer ^> TimerID;
```

What am I doing wrong here ? How to add Tick event proper ?

Comment: Why would you do this? Just use a managed type if you're using a managed timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post enough code to diagnose the error.  This compiles:

```
public ref class Bridge : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
    Timer^ TimerID;
public:
    Bridge(void) {
        InitializeComponent();
        TimerID = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Timer(); 
        TimerID->Tick += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Bridge::timer1_Tick);        
    }
private:
    void Bridge::timer1_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    }
    void InitializeComponent(void) {
        // etc...
    }
};
```

Comment: should be, Bridge is unmanaged class and I'm using gcroot for Timer

Comment: Well, that explains it.  How you managed to compile a native method taking managed objects is a bit mysterious.  You need to use Marshal::GetDelegateForFunctionPointer() to get a delegate object that targets a native function.  The target function must be static, it cannot be an instance method of a class.  Or just set the timer to call a managed method which in turns calls the native method.

Comment: You mean my System::Void Bridge::timer1_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) is unmanaged too and cant be called? Must I make it gcroot?